# requestPermissions doesnt work for READ_CALL_LOG and WRITE_CALL_LOG on android 8.1 API 27

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I`ve been trying to get acces to the calls history and the request permissions seem to not work

the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.stanrares.firstapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

the function that requests permissions:

```
    public void EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs()
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs called");

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"giving read call log permission");
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},
                        1);
                Log.i(TAG,"giving read call log permission 2");
            }

            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Log.i(TAG,"giving write call log permission");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG},
                        1);
                Log.i(TAG,"giving write call log permission 2");

            }
            Log.i(TAG,"EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs called 2");

        }
```

I already tried with tools remove namespace in the manifest file

Comment: "seem to not work" - what exactly does this mean?

Comment: no pop-up appears to request for permission and the app crashes

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.CallLogProvider from ProcessRecord{b85e01b 17217:com.example.stanrares.firstapp/u0a107} (pid=17217, uid=10107) requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
from logcat

Comment: When do you call `EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs()` ? Do you wait for `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to be called (with permission granted) before you call methods that require those permissions?

Comment: Perhaps through earlier tests you effective did a "don't ask again" for this group. Try fully uninstalling and reinstalling your app. Also, I strongly recommend calling `requestPermissions()` once for all of the permissions you need, not once per permission.

Comment: i call EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs()  right at the  beginning of onCreateView function before i do anything else and no i dont wait onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: If you don't wait for `onRequestPermissionsResult` and don't check if those permissions were granted (btw, you're using the same request code for both permission requests - this is wrong, better follow CommonsWare advice), if doesn't matter if `EnableRuntimePermissionToAccessCallLogs` is called right at the beginning if you still call the other stuff without checking if permissions were granted. You should only use methods requiring permissions when you confirm you have those permissions (i.e. in `onRequestPermissionsResult`)

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice, i was able to start the app by manually giving the permissions from settings

Comment: That will work, because while it seems you're calling some method(s) that require permission(s) without waiting for permission request result (and confirming you have those permissions), granting those before the app starts avoids the crash. But you still have problem with the permissions flow in your app. The user can revoke permissions at any time with Runtime Permissions model, so you must **always** check if you have appropriate permission before calling code that requires it.

Comment: yea, ill make sure to fix that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using something like getActivity().getContentResolver().query to get your call log somewhere in your code.

Then you need to provide a ContentProvider to get the URI and implement the query. 
This changed with API26:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#rmp

Post your code and then we can find a solution.